# Is it common that a 7th chord or 9th chord played missing root note and 3rd note?

Tags: guitar, chords

Is it common that a 7th chord or 9th chord played with missing root note and 3rd note? If not
for 7th chords, is it the case for 9th chords?

Comment: I think this is done with major 7th chords in [Magic in the Air](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Zp7KkY6OB8) by Badly Drawn Boy. The piano plays the root note C and then a chord of the notes G and B (i.e. just the fifth and major 7th), then in the next bar it's a root note of F followed by a chord of the notes C and E (likewise). To my ears they are clearly major 7th chords, though perhaps this isn't what you have in mind because the root note is played, *before* the chord.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Particularly for a dominant 7th/9th type chord, omitting the third would be unusual since this loses the tritone between the third and seventh which give the characteristic effect. In general the third is not usually omitted since it defines whether the chord is major or minor.

Omitting the root is common. Omitting an unaltered fifth is probably the most common.

Comment: In an ensemble situation, I can concur that someone can leave out the root, as someone else would play it. But a single player? Can't agree. 5th definitely.

Comment: @Tim Third and seventh are all you need.

Comment: Not according to the Beatles...

Comment: Potato Tomato. You can definitely omit the root of a dominant chord. That happens all the time.  That's what a vii* chord is.  Because it still has the leading tone and the tritone, it retains its dominant function.  Therefore, V7 and vii* are both valid interpretations. If it's not a dominant chord, then this doesn't apply, so its identity would change (eg ii7 w/o the root would just be IV).

Comment: Some times a chord needs to be stated more fully than others.  I'd like to hear the root at a cadence.  In a run of chords, maybe it can be implied?

Answer (score 5):

If you omit the root and the third, the chord will likely change its identity. So for example:

- Cmaj9 would become G
- C9 would become Gm
- Cminmaj9 would become G
- Cm9 would become Gm
- C7b9 would become Gdim
- Cm7b5b9 (Cø7b9) would become Gb

and so on.

This may work, but it would be more likely perceived as reharmonization, rather than a change of voicing. So it's a bit more substantial change.

However, it might be perfectly fine for a single instrument in a band to play incomplete voicing, especially when the other instruments play the missing notes. This may work very well for the upper structures and altered chord tones. Voicings with less notes often sound better.

Still, as PiedPiper said, this might be not the most common choice.

Answer (score 2):

In a dom7 type chord, the minimum 'shell' voicing is the root, 3rd and 7th.  If you're playing alone, the root probably needs to be there, in a band the bass player may be taking care of it (and might be quite happy if you left it to them!)  If the 9th, 13th etc. are important, I guess you'd better play them as well (but be aware they might be being covered by a melody instrument).   So, as so often, 'it all depends...'.   Leaving out the 5th is a pretty safe bet though.

Comment: In e.g. a C major duet, a resolution which resolves from F-B to E-C is often more satisfying than one which resolves from G-B to G-C or E-C, or one that resolves from F-G to E-C.

Answer (score 1):

What would a seventh chord be called if there was no root? And the 3rd is paramount - is it major or minor? So, basically, without the root, it's not called that particular 7th (or 9th), and without the 3rd, it's not a m7 (m9), so it's not the same named chord whatever. So, in essence, the root, 3rd and whatever extensions will define the chord in question. Why wouldn't they?

Comment: I dunno. There are occasional two note voicings that are just 3rd and 7th. If you have the context of the surrounding tonal center then a 3rd and 7th can be all you need. You can get away with a root and 7th only in the same situations for the same reasons. But leaving out both is unlikely to be heard as the intended chord.